# Is there Ubuntu software for architectural drafting

Tags: cad

I want to draw plans for domestic buildings and be able to estimate materials and costings. Is there relatively simple CAD software available. I've searched extensively with no success.

Comment: Also [Any 3D CAD programs for Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/327807/301745), [CAD - Ubuntu Engineering - Community Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuEngineering#CAD), [Top 5 CAD Software Available for Linux in 2019 - It's FOSS](https://itsfoss.com/cad-software-linux/), [Good floor planner program?](https://askubuntu.com/q/27093/301745)

Answer (score 0):

### DraftSight

DraftSight by Dassault is a free, but not opensource, 2D CAD drafting program.
It is nearly identical in operation to Autodesk AutoCAD and uses native DWG format.
There should be no learning curve for a regular AutoCAD user.

https://www.3ds.com/products-services/draftsight-cad-software/free-download/

DraftSight does have many 3D capabilities such as 3D Orbit, 3D Polyline and 3D Mesh. However it can nor create or modify 3D ACIS solids.